Custom role read-only for detail server in OpenStack
I want to create a custom read-only role that can show server details in all other projects "openstack server show" without needing to assign the role to the project.
Here I have set the following rules in nova and keystone policy.json:
nova
{
"os_compute_api:servers:show": "role:admin or role:l1",
"os_compute_api:servers:detail": "role:admin or role:l1",
"os_compute_api:servers:index": "role:admin or role:l1",
"os_compute_api:servers:allow_all_filters": "role:admin or role:l1"
}

keystone
{
"identity:list_projects": "role:admin or role:l1",
"identity:get_project": "role:admin or role:l1"
}

when doing a server list on all projects it was successful, but when displaying server details on another project (openstack server show) I still got the message "No server with a name or ID of 'xxxxx' exists."
I've tried adding permissions related to the list and show projects in Keystone but it still doesn't work.
Are there any rules I haven't followed?
Thank You
can display server details in other projects without having to add a user role to the project.
